# Increasing targetSdkVersion causes gradle build failure

Tags: android

Please help, I am not sure what is missing.. ? I am working on updating an existing android app with small requirement changes from business. Existing app had compiledSdkVersion = 19 and targetSdkVersion = 22. I would like to increase both to 23. Existing version name was 1.6 and hence increased it to 1.7. Version code is set by using advanced versioning. When I increment the values I am receiving NullPointerException : Cannot invoke method canRead() on null object. Here is my build file and the exception stacktrace.  I am using Android Studio to build the app.

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: '*.jar', dir: 'libs')
    compile project(':pulltorefresh')
compile project(':StickyListHeaders_lib')
    // compile 'se.emilsjolander:stickylistheaders:2.6.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    //compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0@aar'
    compile 'net.sf.kxml:kxml2:2.3.0'
    compile 'xmlwise:xmlwise:1.2.11'
       compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:cr.   ashlytics:2.4.0@aar') {
    transitive = true;
    }
}
```

//Define version of map plist files used for map
def plist_version = "17"

android {

```
//compileSdkVersion 19
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.x.y"
    versionName "1.7"
    // Requires creation of empty file {Project Root}/y/version.properties
    buildConfigField "int", "PLIST_VERSION", plist_version
    //targetSdkVersion 22
    targetSdkVersion 23
}
sourceSets {
    main {
        manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        java.srcDirs = ['src']
        resources.srcDirs = ['src']
        aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
        renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
        res.srcDirs = ['res']
        assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
    }


    debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
    release.setRoot('build-types/release')
}
productFlavors {
}
```

}

Stacktrace :

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':Butlins'.

  > Cannot invoke method canRead() on null object
- Try:
  Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
- Exception is:
  org.gradle.api.ProjectConfigurationException: A problem occurred configuring project ':Butlins'.
  at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.addConfigurationFailure(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:79)
  at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.notifyAfterEvaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:74)
  at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:61)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:510)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:90)
  at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configure(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:35)
  at org.gradle.execution.TaskSelector.getSelection(TaskSelector.java:82)
  at org.gradle.execution.TaskSelector.getSelection(TaskSelector.java:75)
  .... and more

Comment: It is not related to your issue, but are you sure to use com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0@aar today?

Comment: Got this working by adding the below line after advancedversioning code  -println advancedVersioning.versionCode